# Can't connect Celery server to RabbitMQ on localhost

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery

I am using Celery and RabbitMQ as a message queue, where each is encapsulated in it's own Docker image. When they are connected using the `--link` parameter in Docker, everything works fine. I've had this setup working for some time now. I want to separate them so that they run on different hosts, so I can no longer use the `--link` parameter for this. I am getting a `gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known` when I try to connect using AMQP and don't understand why.

The server is simply using the `rabbitmq` container on DockerHub:

```
docker run --rm --name=qrabbit -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq
```

I can telnet to this successfully:

```
$ telnet 192.168.99.100 5672
Trying 192.168.99.100...
Connected to 192.168.99.100.
Escape character is '^]'.
abc
^D
AMQP    Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

... so I know the server is running.

My client looks like this:

```
import os

from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, DEBUG
from serverlib import QueueServer, CeleryMonitor
from celery import Celery
from argparse import ArgumentParser

log = getLogger('server')
log.addHandler(StreamHandler())
log.setLevel(DEBUG)

broker_service_host = os.environ.get('MESSAGE_QUEUE_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST')

broker = 'amqp://{0}'.format(broker_service_host)
host = ''
port = 8000
retry = 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log.info('connecting to {0}, {1}:{2}, retry={3}'.format(broker, host, port, retry))
    app = Celery(broker=broker)
    monitor = CeleryMonitor(app, retry=retry)
    server = QueueServer((host, port), app)
    monitor.start()
    try:
        log.info('listening on {0}:{1}'.format(host, port))
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        log.info('shutdown requested')
    except BaseException as e:
        log.error(e)
    finally:
        monitor.shutdown()
```

I'm somewhat certain the external modules (QueueServer and CeleryMonitor) are not part of the problem, as it runs properly when I do the following:

```
 $ docker run --rm --name=qmaster -e "MESSAGE_QUEUE_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=localhost" --link qrabbit:rabbit -p 80:8000 render-task-master
connecting to amqp://localhost, :8000, retry=5
listening on :8000
^Cshutdown requested
$
```

... but not if I do the following (without the `--link` parameter):

```
$  docker run --rm --name=qmaster -e "MESSAGE_QUEUE_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=localhost" -p 80:8000 render-task-master
connecting to amqp://localhost, :8000, retry=5
listening on :8000
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/celery/serverlib/celerymonitor.py", line 68, in run
    '*': self.__state.event
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/events/__init__.py", line 287, in __init__
    self.channel = maybe_channel(channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 1054, in maybe_channel
    return channel.default_channel
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 756, in default_channel
    self.connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 741, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 696, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqp.py", line 116, in establish_connection
    conn = self.Connection(**opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.transport = self.Transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 186, in Transport
    return create_transport(host, connect_timeout, ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 299, in create_transport
    return TCPTransport(host, connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 75, in __init__
    socket.SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

^Cshutdown requested
$
```

What is the difference between using and not using the `--link` parameter that might cause this error?

**UPDATE:**

I've narrowed it down to an error in the monitor class I created:

```
recv = self.app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
    'task-received': self.registerTask,
    'task-failed': self.retryTask,
    'task-succeeded': self.deregisterTask,
    # should process all events to have state up to date
    '*': self.__state.event 
})
```

When this is called, it sits for a few seconds (timeout?) and then throws an exception. Any idea why this wouldn't like the amqp URL specified as `amqp://localhost` but everything works correctly when I use the --link parameter?

Here's the whole method that call is in, for additional context:

```
def run(self):
    log.info('run')
    self.__state = self.app.events.State()
    with self.app.connection() as connection:
        log.info('got a connection')
        recv = self.app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
            'task-received': self.registerTask,
            'task-failed': self.retryTask,
            'task-succeeded': self.deregisterTask,
            # should process all events to have state up to date
            '*': self.__state.event 
        })
        log.info('received receiver')
        # Capture until shutdown requested
        while not self.__shutdown:
            log.info('main run loop')
            try:
                recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=1, wakeup=True)
            except timeout:
                # timeout exception is fired when nothing occurs
                # during timeout. Just ignore it.
                pass
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your environment but couldn't find the `serverlib` library in pypi. Obviously th problem is within the `QueueServer.serve_forever()` which I had to comment out. However you should be aware that the `--link` option has been deprecated in favor of the networks feature. See the docs [here](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/)

Comment: I've isolated it down to a call in the Celery monitor class I have:

        recv = self.app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={
            'task-received': self.registerTask,
            'task-failed': self.retryTask,
            'task-succeeded': self.deregisterTask,
            # should process all events to have state up to date
            '*': self.__state.event 
        })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue: I had set `CELERY_BROKER_URL` in the Docker environment in which the container was running and this was causing the backend to attempt to connect to a hostname that did not exist. Once I un-set the variable, everything hooked up properly in my environment.

```
$ docker inspect server
<... removed ...>
        "Env": [
        "MESSAGE_QUEUE_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=192.168.99.100",
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
        "LANG=C.UTF-8",
        "PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.10",
        "PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=7.1.2",
        "CELERY_VERSION=3.1.18",
        "CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://guest@rabbit"
    ],
<... removed ...>
```

Comment: can you update your answer with, how you updated `container` config? I also face same issue, don't know how to update config :(

Comment: I actually don't have any config in the container, instead I put the config in the environment. What part of the config are you interested in?